# When I using the delete button , I get a error message....How to solve this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)

  {
        string year = tb_year.Text;
        string gross = tb_gross.Text;
        string rating = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        string director = tb_director.Text;string sel = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

 string query = "UPDATE MovieList SET ReleaseYear=@YearValue," +
                       "Gross=@GrossValue, Rating=@RatingValue," +
                       "Director=@DirectorValue WHERE Rank=@SelValue";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand ocmd =
             new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query,
             new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(CSTR));

        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearValue", year);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrossValue", gross);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RatingValue", rating);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DirectorValue", director);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelValue", sel);

        ocmd.Connection.Open();
        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ocmd.Connection.Close();

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string year = tb_year.Text;
        string gross = tb_gross.Text;
        string rating = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
        string director = tb_director.Text;

        string sel = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        string query = "DELETE FROM MovieList WHERE Movie=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand ocmd =
             new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query,
             new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(CSTR));

        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearValue", year);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrossValue", gross);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RatingValue", rating);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DirectorValue", director);
        ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelValue", sel);

        ocmd.Connection.Open();
        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  <<***
        ocmd.Connection.Close();
        populateDropDowns();
    }
}
}
```

The button 1 is a update button, when I change the value, it can be update the database information and this button can update the information immediate.

But the Delete button, when I delete the information, it will throw an error message:

> "OleDbException was unhandled by user code : Additional information:
>   Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Movie=The Matrix
>   Revolutions''. in "***".

However, when I open this website again, the information is deleted. How to solve this error message and delete the information immediate??

Comment: you are missing the opening `'` in your query string.  That being said, you shouldn't ever build a query string that way.

Comment: After I add the ' in query, it can delete the item but the item name is still in website page. And when I click this item name, it will has others error message.....

Comment: this code doesn't show you doing anything at all to update the UI, and of course it will error if you try to delete an item that is already deleted.  If you aren't sure how to update the dropdown, you may need to post a new question with the code relevant to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the same way like you did with your update, use SQL parameters for the where clause. So this code should work:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sel = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    // if your selection is empty, abort early
    if( sel == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(sel.Text)) return;

    // use a SQL parameter like you did with update
    string query = "DELETE FROM MovieList WHERE Movie=@MovieValue";

    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand ocmd =
         new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query,
         new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(CSTR));

    // here the selected text for the movie is set to the movie parameter
    ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieValue", sel.Text);

    ocmd.Connection.Open();
    ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ocmd.Connection.Close();
    populateDropDowns();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string query = "DELETE FROM MovieList WHERE Movie='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
```

You should change your query with the above, you are missing `'`

Comment: Do *not* do this as you're opening yourself up to SQL injections, use parameterised queries as is done in the `Button1_Click1` method.

Comment: Please don't "teach" people how to write code with SQL injection possibilities "correct". The correct way is to use parameters like the rest of the parameters the OP has used.

Comment: Yes we should use parameters.